# Vb .net regex dot use

Tags: .net, regex

I want to use regex pattern:

```
   Dim today As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("today_count"">$(\d+\.\d+)")
```

My input contains followed text:

```
<span class="balanceAmount" id="today_live">$0.42</span> </a>
```

And it gaves me nothing. I also tried something like this:

```
   Dim today As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("today_count"">$(.+)<")
```

or

```
   Dim today As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("today_count"">$(*+)<")
```

And still nothing. Can you guys help me?

Comment: What do you want to get?

Comment: numbers between `$` and `>`. In that example that would be `0.42`

Comment: @audiophonic: `<span class="balanceAmount" id="today_live">$0.42</span> </a>` does not contain `today_count` and `$` must be escaped `\$`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654554/vb-net-regex-dot-use?noredirect=1#comment60903589_36654554) comment, try this pattern:

```
/\$([\d\.]+)/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aT3qN3/3)

- `/` delimiter
- `\$` matches the character $ literally
- `(` capturing group
- `[\d\.]+` matches one or more digit and dot

Comment: I do not understand whats for is delimiter. Is it neccesary?

Comment: @audiophonic Yes it is, You have to determine both begin and end of your pattern.

Comment: But `$` exist in every text. Would be properly to use: `/([\d\.]+)/` ?

Comment: @audiophonic I have used `$` as a clue to find expected number. If there isn't any number else *(in other word, if your string is only containing one number and it is expected number)*, then yes, you can remove it and use that pattern you have mentioned.

Comment: But can you tell me what is the difference between `/\$([\d\.]+)/` and `\$([\d\.]+)`?In regex101.com its not necessary to use delimiter so i cant undestand what's it for.

Comment: When i used your pattern with `/` it was not working. When i used: `\$([\d\.]+)` it was working like a charm. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @audiophonic I'm not sure, but maybe you have used `"` delimited instead of `/`. something like this: `"\$([\d\.]+)"`